# Testing a real TCP Socket in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sockets, testing, tcp, socketpair

I have a program that operates on a socket via the Rack hijack. I would like to test that program using a real TCP socket, and I want to receive what it sends to the socket and check that I get the right results.

How do I go about this? I tried using Socketpair:

```
@sender, @receiver = Socket.pair(:INET, :STREAM, 1024 * 256)`
```

and then

```
hijack_proc = h.fetch('rack.hijack')
hijack_proc.call(@sender)
```

but all I get is `Protocol not supported - socketpair(2)`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [Netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat)?
You should be able to use something like `netcat -l 4444` in a terminal window, and give `4444` as the port to your program to connect to.
Once your program sends something to Netcat, and you see it in your terminal, you can type your 'response' and press `Enter` to send that text back to your program.

Comment: Not quite. I would like to read what gets written to the socket from within of my test (it is the test that creates the `@sender`)

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. It does not seem useful to me to check what gets written to the Socket though, because that would be testing Ruby's socket functionality

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847554/mock-tcpsocket-in-rspec
... And you can set your expectation on the null object mock: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-6/docs/method-stubs/as-null-object

Comment: I can test this with a mock for sure, but I am looking more for the real thing (because the library I am testing also uses things like `sendfile()`)